# angular4 - access child route of a route which uses a parameter

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have routes which look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent,
    children:[
              { path: '', redirectTo: 'cat', pathMatch: 'full' },
              { path: 'cat',  component: CatComponent},
              { path: 'dog',  component: DogComponent},
              { path: 'vet/:id',  component: VetComponent,
                children:[
                          { path: '', redirectTo: 'hospital', pathMatch: 'full' },
                          { path: 'hospital',  component: HospitalComponent},
                          { path: 'clinic',  component: ClinicComponent}
                ]}
    ]},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

I am then trying to access the the clinic path so :

```
/home/vet/9999/clinic
```

So I tried the following:

```
this.router.navigate(['/home/vet/clinic', 9999]);
this.router.navigate(['/home/vet/:id/clinic', 9999]);
```

but I keep getting redirected to the login page.

I need to be able to go to the clinic page and also have access to the id variable. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The when you call it it needs to look like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/home/vet', 9999, 'clinic']);
```

instead of

```
this.router.navigate(['/home/vet/clinic', 9999]);
```